# How to set a password in my Excel sheet in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

I want to protect an Excel Sheet.
I tried officeapp.protect("mypassowrd") but it's not working.

```
Dim docPath As String = 
 Path.Combine(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath,"CURRICULUM.xlsx")
 Dim officeapp As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
 officeapp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
  Dim workbook As Object = officeapp.Workbooks.Add(docPath)
  officeapp.Visible = True


 With officeapp

.Range("A" + (10).ToString).Value =  "i want to protect this rows"
.Range("B" + (10).ToString`).Value = "i want to protect this rows"
.Range("C" + (10).ToString).Value = "i want to protect this rows"

End With

        officeapp = Nothing
        workbook = Nothing
        officeapp.protect("mypassowrd")
 Me.Refresh()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is method inside

```
Excel.Application  
Dim objExcel As New Excel.Application  
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs()

Sub SaveAs(Optional Filename As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional FileFormat As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional Password As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional WriteResPassword As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional ReadOnlyRecommended As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional CreateBackup As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional AccessMode As Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode = xlNoChange,
           Optional ConflictResolution As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional AddToMru As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional TextCodepage As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional TextVisualLayout As Object = Nothing, 
           Optional Local As Object = Nothing)
 Member of Excel._Workbook
```